# Fair way to split coins

Tags: logical-deduction, money

> Alice and Bob went walking in the desert.
>   Alice had two gallons of water and Bob had three gallons.
>   They met Charlie who had no water at all and they all (Alice, Bob, and Charlie) shared the five gallons of water evenly.
>   As a token of his gratitude, Charlie gave them five gold coins.
>   What is the fair way to split these five coins?

Source: [Ponder This](http://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/August2018.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alice has 6/3 gallons of water. Bob has 9/3 gallons of water.

After sharing the five gallons of water evenly,

> Alice has given Charlie 1/3 gallons of water and Bob has given him 4/3 gallons of water.

As such, I believe Alice should get

> 1 gold coin

and Bob

> the other four - the effective trade is 1 gold coin for 1/3 gallons of water, here.

Comment: That's one way of looking at it. Another, from the economists: using logarithmic utility. Alice, who has less water to begin with, is likely to value it more. 'Fair', should reflect that.